# DNS MX record lookup on Oreo and above

Tags: java, android, dns, lookup, mx-record

On lookup dns mx records an the android OS8 platform, I am always getting null on new Lookup("gmail.com", Type.MX).run(). I am using dnsjava-2.1.8.jar (http://www.dnsjava.org/)

```
Record[] mxRecords = new Lookup("gmail.com", Type.MX).run();
for (Record mxRecord : mxRecords) {
    MXRecord mx = (MXRecord) mxRecord;
    targets.add(mx.getTarget().toString());
}
```

I have internet permission in manifest.

Comment: Where are you getting null? `run()`, `mxRecord`, `targets`, `getTarget()`?

Comment: Which query, for what domain? Can you reproduce the result when trying from another host? Not all domains have `MX` records...

Comment: @TheWanderer I am getting null at run()

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I am checking for gmail.com. Updated my question.

Comment: Possibly related to DNS privacy changes from Android 8.0. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes

Comment: @user3144836 I have this problem aswell, any update on this? I dont see "net.hostname" in the dnsjava codebase

Comment: @urSus Unfortunately there are no updates yet.

Comment: @user3144836 youll need to for the dnsjava and replace findAndroid method with the connectivitymanager api